# SuiteScript SCA - Validating a form field

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am attempting to validate a form field for an SCA (mont-blanc) site.
As I am not versed in SuiteScript code, but know Java, I simply need to know how to retrieve the POST value of a form field, so that I can do a check on the submission before submitting the form.

The below is not working - simply because I don't know the function / method to call to get the email address that is being submitted.

```
name: 'ContactUs',
       create: function create( data ) {
            try {
                url = '<the-url>';
                var email = nlapiGetContext.getEmail();
                if (email.indexOf("qq.com") === -1) {
                    response = nlapiRequestURL(url, data);

                    responseCode = parseInt(respons...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting the value in a data field in a submitted form is as simple as data['field_name']

In the above example - it would be:

```
name: 'ContactUs',
       create: function create( data ) {
            try {
                url = '<the-url>';
                **var email = data['email'];**
                if (email.indexOf("qq.com") === -1) {
                    response = nlapiRequestURL(url, data);

                    responseCode = parseInt(respons...
```

Answer (score 1):

To validate any field data you need to use client-script on the said record and based on your code and requirement, I think you want to validate Suitelet data(right?).
You can deploy client script on any record/suitelet and validate field data in **saveRecord** method. You can find client script help doc [here](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4410693749.html).

Comment: Would this catch submissions that are NOT sent via the form. (i.e. validateform onsubmit never fires)?  We're getting a script bot or something that is firing directly to the submission URL.  So I have to catch it at the time of submit.  Which the above function is.  I simply need to be able to access the POST form value 'email' and do a few tests on it to block certain domains.  In this case, qq.com.